# convert hachures (not only solid) from tiff or pdf to polygon shapes?

Tags: qgis, convert

Is there a possibility in QGIS to convert hachures from tiff or PDF to polygon shapes?

[image]

Comment: Try the Polygonize tool in the Raster menu.